# How to mount increased volume to root in EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I did the mistake of increasing the volume without having the snapshot of it. I am running a wordpress website in t2.large EC2 instance. So after I increased the volume from 8GB to 16GB, I am not able to see any page in wordpress admin.

[image]

How to do I restore it back to my initial configuration. Or is it possible to mount the increased volume to root without losing any data or hampering state of website.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you increase the size of an EBS volume, you will need to increase the size of the actual file system.

If you are using ext2, 3 or 4 you can use (as root) resize2fs.  For XFS, try xfs_growfs.